# Where is the Login/Logout link for this site?

Tags: discussion

I created an account and logged in and asked a question from my laptop at home. While at work, I received an alert, which I viewed on my PC at work. I wanted to add a comment but got a message that I could not unless logged in, and the only login options were Facebook, Google+ etc, and not the username and password. Why it is not top right like the vast majority of sites is a bit of a mystery, so I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

At the top right is a little logo that looks like a speech bubble. If you click it, it exposes a drop down menu. The first row will include a link called 'Log Out.'

[image]

On mobile, this is nearly the same, except that the link is on the far left of the header.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Logout is on the top right at stackexchange.